# Unable to find element in Selenium, Python for submitting a search query

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting out with Selenium, trying to enter the text and press a submit button, so that it navigates to that search result page.
I have tried:

1. find an element by class name, but doesn't work as it has space. I have read the docs on locating elements, but I am unable to figure out what would work for me here.
2. Simulate Enter key press, to submit it.

None seem to work, any suggestions on how I can locate this button and press/click on it?

**Inspected page shows:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Submit" onclick="$('#form_topsearch').submit();" class="btn_black btn_search FR"></a>
```

**My code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# imported keys tp try Enter key simualtion.


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com")
searchText = driver.find_element_by_id("search_str")
searchText.send_keys("dlf")
# works fine till now, enters the text:
# but unable to submit the entry.
```

Comment: to click on submit button, for xpath you can use title

Comment: tried, but didnt work out. Could you map the xpath, maybe I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filling "search text" ("dlf" in your case) -- click on the "Search" button:

```
search_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn_black.btn_search.FR")
search_button.click()
```

And you will get search results.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: can you please elaborate how css_selector turns out to be ".btn_black.btn_search.FR"

Comment: class="btn_black btn_search FR" , so isn't this the  class name?

Comment: @cicilia, there are 3 classes: btn_black, btn_search, FR for this element. For more reliable identification of element, I used CSS selector, because there can be other elements with such class names.

Comment: @cicilia, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: So i can use either of those name too? provided all three are unique to that element?

Comment: Also could you point me t some resources for learning to locate elements in page.

Comment: @cicilia, 1) http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html; 2) http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#locating-ui-elements-webelements.